# Whenever I try to add a button to my actionbar, the items are added under the overflow menu

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add a simple button to my action bar, but when I try to use the following code, the items are added as items under the overflow menu, not on the actionbar itself.  Any help would be appreciated,

Jacob

Here is my Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_review, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;



        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

and my XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item android:id="@+id/seda"
        android:icon="@drawable/redpinreal"
        android:title="Hello Worldh"
        android:showAsAction="withText|always"/>

</menu>
```

I also have this enabled:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your code (`android:showAsAction`, instead of `yourapp:showAsAction`) is attempting to use the native action bar. Part of your code (`getSupportActionBar()`, instead of `getActionBar()`) is attempting to use the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport. **Choose one** and stick with it.

Comment: Hello, that worked but the text doesn't show up next to the icon

Comment: @JacobPlatin: You could try putting `always` first, before `withText`, as I normally see it in that order. Otherwise, the action bar implementation thinks that there is not enough room for the title. Try rotating the device/emulator to landscape and see if it shows up. `withText` is a hint, not a command, and the title will not always be visible on the action bar itself.